# С какими предлогами можно употреблять глагол "погружаться"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Согласно словарям, погружаться - опускаться во что-либо. Рассмотрим глагол именно в этом значении. Формально рассуждая, можно только "погружаться в". На практике ни у кого не вызывают возражения выражения "погружаться на дно" и "погружаться под воду". Оказывается, в Сети можно найти также выражения "погружаться ко дну", "погружаться к затонувшему кораблю". Не произошла ли подмена "спускаться" на "погружаться"? Помогите отделить зерна от плевел.

P.S.

Понятно, что дополнение, отвечающее на вопрос куда?, может быть опущено, например, "погрузиться [в воду] на глубину 10 метров". Но все равно не могу понять, как можно "погрузиться [в воду] ко дну". Здесь согласование потеряно.

Answer (score 1):

**Не произошла ли подмена "спускаться" на "погружаться"?**

Вот примеры, которые показывают, что не всё так просто. Нарочно выбрал среди всех вариантов только добротные издания, чтобы не испытывать ненужных сомнений относительно качества.

> Звезды, которые прошлый раз виднелись на западе, погрузились под
>   горизонт... (Г.Рей, "Звёзды", изд-во "Мир", 1969.)
>
> ...Впервые ... погрузились под 5%-ную черту. (Изд-во "Наука", 1988 г.)

Особенно интересна первая цитата, поскольку в других подобных фразах в этой книге говорится "опустились под горизонт". И это издание полувековой давности, а не последние веяния.

Судя по этим и другим примерам, я делаю для себя вывод, что действительно имеется какая-то диффузия понятий, которая не отмечена пока словарями.

Answer (score 0):

**погружаться**
**1)** *опускаться во что-либо (жидкость, снег, песок и т. п.)*.
**В рамках соревнований... установила новый мировой рекорд в дисциплине "свободное погружение по тросу" — 92 метра.**

**2)** перен. *приходить в какое-либо физическое или психическое состояние; целиком отдаваться чему-либо*.
**Лес погрузился во мрак.**

**3)** *наполняться товарами, кладью, вещами и т. п.(т.е. грузом) для перевозки.*
**Погрузить лес на баржу.**

**4)** о человеке или животном: *поместиться в поезд, на пароход и т. п. для перевозки.*
**Глава большой семьи огляделся и тяжело вздохнул:

-Ну, все погрузились? С богом!**

В дискуссии о Марианской впадине имелось в виду первое значение:

**погрузился** ко дну   =   **опустился в воду** ко дну.

*Другие примеры:*

**погрузились** на глубину 300 метров = **опустились в воду** на глубину 300 метров;
антилопа уже **погрузилась** по самую шею, она погибала = антилопа уже **опустилась в песок** по самую шею, она погибала;
...прыгнул, и нога **погрузилась** до колена = ...прыгнул, и нога **опустилась в снег** до колена;
свободное **погружение** по тросу = свободное **опускание в воду** по тросу.

Думаю, что именно в этом значении глагол **погружаться** ( и его производные ) можно употреблять практически с любыми предлогами:
***ко*** дну, **до** отметки, **в** скафандре,  **по** тросу, **с** оборудованием, **на** глубину, **к** развалинам, **под** наблюдением, **за** сокровищами...

**Дополнение**

*Давайте посмотрим на снимки одного из последний **погружений к** затонувшему "Титанику", останки которого были обнаружены на дне ...*

*Просто продолжайте дышать и **погружаться к** более глубоким и спокойным слоям.*

*Президент России Владимир Путин во вторник, 18 августа, **погрузился** в батискафе **к** древнему судну, которое затонуло в Балаклавской бухте в районе Севастополя.*

Comment: Пробую следовать Вашей схеме. Получается: (1) Опустился в воду ко дну? Неувязочка с согласованием. (2) Опустился в воду под воду? Опять неувязка.

Comment: Почему же?  Батискаф опустился в воду ко дну ( к самому дну ), ...к одной из скал, ...к условленной отметке, ...к античной статуе

Comment: Сравните: Я вошел в лес к избушке лесника, въехал в город к моему дому. Разве так говорят?

Comment: Нет, конечно, ТАК не говорят. Но: я направился в лес к избушке лесника.

Comment: Вашу мысль не улавливаю. "Погрузился" похоже на "вошел" или на "направился"?

Comment: Нет.  Погрузился = опустился в воду, в сироп, в раствор, в снег, в песок...      ...он обернулся и понял, что туша  погрузилась ( опустилась в трясину ) с ужасающим звуком... ( не дословно )

Answer (score 0):

**ПОГРУЗИТЬСЯ**,  св. 1.  **Опуститься** во что-л. жидкое, сыпучее и т.п.

**ОПУСТИТЬСЯ**, -св. 1. Переместиться, **спуститься вниз**, занять более низкое положение. О. в подвал. О. в колодец. О. на дно.

Итак, погрузиться – это опуститься вниз (направление уже указано), и именно  внизу расположено дно. Соответственно,   выражение "опуститься ко дну" **содержит тавтологию (поэтому и кажется на слух неверным),** опускаться можно только вниз  (указывать направление здесь не требуется, но можно указать, на какую глубину вы опускаетесь). Поэтому правильным является выражение **погрузиться на дно,** если при этом вы достигли уровня дна.

Из текста:

(1) Первыми людьми, которые лично погружались **к дну** Марианской впадины, стали швейцарский океанолог Жак Пикар и военнослужащий США Дон Уолш. Это произошло в январе 1960 года. [Марианская впадина — самое глубокое и таинственное место на земле | samosov.ru](http://samosov.ru/marianskaya-vpadina-samoe-glubokoe-i-tainstvennoe-mesto-na-zemle/)

(2) Таким образом, единственными людьми, отважившимися погрузиться **на «дно земли»,** были американский морской специалист Дон Уолш и швейцарский ученый Жак Пикар. На том же самом батискафе «Триест» они 23 января 1960 года **достигли дна**, опустившись на глубину 10915 метров.
[Марианская впадина | interesnyefakty.org](http://interesnyefakty.org/marianskaya-vpadina/)

**Вывод:** Думаю, что в тексте (1)  надо сказать "погружались **на дно** Марианской впадины", тем более что дна они действительно достигли.

Comment: А что скажете по поводу "погружаться к затонувшему кораблю" (из новостей в Сети)

Comment: Возможно, происходит расширение значения слова, так как учитывается движение по двум направлениям: по вертикали вниз и по горизонтали к нужному объекту. Тогда "погружались ко дну впадины" тоже можно рассматривать как движение к различным точкам этой впадины, которые могут располагаться на разных глубинах. Поэтому предлог К относится к  движению по горизонтали с одновременным погружением вниз.